# Why isn't python solving this matrix correclty?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I'm trying to experiment with using Matrices to solve polynomial expressions, and it worked so far.

In my code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [4,2,1], [9,3,1]])
B = np.array([2, 5, 10])
sol = np.linalg.solve(A, B)


print(sol)
```

Array A is just the first 3 values required to solve for a quadratic. Array B is for x^2 + 1. 
So The output of the function should be:

[1. 0. 1.]

Instead, I'm getting:
[ 1.00000000e+00 -8.32667268e-16  1.00000000e+00]

I get the e+00, but why is the second value "-8.32667268e-16"??
I've double checked my math and it should be x^2 + 1.

Comment: Up to rounding error, that *is* zero.

Comment: Do you understand what `1e-16` represents?

Comment: -8e-16 is a very small number. I think a floating point rounding error has occured. Are you sure you need to solve this polynomial expression with 16 digits of precision?

Comment: You might be interested in using exact arithmetic instead of floating point, which is approximate. I haven't checked, but it seems likely that Sympy (sympy.org) can do arithmetic with rational numbers, which is exact. Especially if you are working with polynomials, the difference between exact and approximate arithmetic may be substantial.

Comment: For exact solutions, have a look at sympy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well technically, it's -8x10^(-16) ~= 0, hence the answer is correct.
Although you can format it to be exactly 0 using either a sigmoid function or just using Rolle's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

`-8.32667268e-16` = -0.0000000000000008326… It’s a floating point rounding error. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because during the matrix operations, the numbers get rounded slightly. Try:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
              [4, 2, 1],
              [9, 3, 1]])

B = np.array([2, 5, 10])
sol = [round(n) for n in np.linalg.solve(A, B)]

print(sol)
```

Output:

```
 [1.0, -0.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Is there a way to round it off to a specific decimal point?

Comment: Yes: `round(n,2)` is the default, you can change the number.